# Process Still Running After Closing Debugger

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, process

It seems like a process is still running after I close the form (closing the form via X) while debugging.

How do I go about making sure all process are ended when the form closes?

Here is the current code I'm running which I think is causing the problem.

```
Using psinfo As New Process
   psinfo.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe "
   psinfo.StartInfo.Arguments = Arg1 + ZipFileName + PathToPDFs
   psinfo.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
   psinfo.Start()
   psinfo.WaitForExit()
End Using
```

Comment: The form being a WinForms form, or a form belonging to the process you started?

Comment: This is almost always caused by a thread that didn't have its IsBackground property set to true.  If you have no clue then use Debug + Break All, Debug + Windows + Threads.  See what those threads are doing.

Comment: This is a WinForms form...within the form, a button is used to start the process listed above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dim p as process
 for each p in system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyname("your exe")
  p.kill()
```

Comment: So this just gets a list of each specific process by the given name and kills each of them?